# antcall target="release" breaks with google-play-services_lib

Tags: android, ant, google-play-services

I am trying to build my android apps from command line, I have a script

`ant release`

fails at

```
BUILD FAILED
android-sdk-macosx/tools/ant/build.xml:473: Invalid file: myProject/google-play-services_lib/build.xml
```

this is necessary for the android google maps v2 api

I tried to add my other build.xml to the `google-play-services_lib` but then it didn't recognize my directories particualr the variables `sdk.dir`

how do I fix this and add this library to my ant build?

Comment: also note: building from within Eclipse using the export command does not break and the apk works fine on a device. This is not an option for me as my script does a lot of configuring to build many apps out of this code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is that

```
ant.properties
local.properties
build.xml
```

all need to be copied into the google-play-services_lib folder.

ant.properties needs to be edited to look up one more directory `../` for the keystore.

and if you have any custom rules, you need to edit the copied build.xml to look up one more directory for those rules `../`

Comment: Hi...i have the same problem, but i am first time user of a ant... Can you help me and in details explain??? For example: from where to copy ant what does this files have in it?! Than what exactly to put in ant.properties? What rules do you mean? I will be very gratefull for help... Thanks

Comment: hm @Jovan I answered assuming that you would have a project already working with ant before you added google-play-services, I would try to remove the google-play components and see if you can build with ant first. If so, then your project's root directory will have all of the three files I mentioned. Then just copy those files into the google-play-services_lib folder within your project

Comment: I have a project that is builded wwith ant. When i add google-play-service and try build it breaks... This files, from where did you copy it?

Comment: these three files were in my project's root directory @Jovan

Comment: I needed just build file...normal build file, becuse build file from my project has some ant command that are important only for him. Thanks again CQM...

Answer (score 3):

Do a `android update project -p myProject/google-play-services_lib`